# Base de Datos en Windows Form

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un Windows Forms echo en Visual Basic, quisiera saber si hay alguna versión de SQL que pueda ir con el instalador? Es decir, cuando ejecuto el instalador en una computadora que le instale el motor de base de datos también. 
El sistema es bastante chico y utiliza Entity Framework

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cualquier versión puede ir con el instalador. Lo importante es saber como hacer una [instalación desatendida de SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/instalacion-desatendida-de-sql-server/). El problema podría ser la licencia y la validación de que no exista ya una instancia corriendo en la computadora que se instale. La versión recomendada podría ser la Express para no tener que pagar licencias por equipo, bajo la consideración de que las bases de datos están limitadas a 10GB y no tiene el agente disponible para tareas automáticas. En sí, SQL Server está diseñado para trabajar en un esquema cliente-servidor y no ser instalado en cada equipo, pero dependiendo de las necesidades puede que sea lo que necesites.